# Floating DIV work right in Firefox, but not correctly in IE9 and Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-tables

Let's say I have following [table like this](http://jsfiddle.net/7u6ye/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <link href="Theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Calendar" style="float:right;">
        <div id="calHeader">
            <div class="header">
                <div></div>
                <div class="title">awr awrawra</div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="calDays">
            <div id="calDaysWeek">
                <div>Monday</div>
                <div>Tuesday</div>
                <div>Wednesday</div>
                <div>Thursday</div>
                <div>Friday</div>
                <div>Saturday</div>
                <div>Sunday</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    #Calendar
    {
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    #Calendar div
    {
        border: solid 1px black;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #calHeader,
    #calDays
    {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
    }
    #calHeader > div, #calDays > div
    {
        display:table-row;
    }
    #calHeader > div > div,
    #calDays > div > div
    {
        display:table-cell;
    }
    #calHeader > div > div
    {
        width: 50%;
    }

    #calHeader .header .title
    {
        width:inherit;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

    #calDaysWeek div
    {
        width: 100px;
    }

    #calDays .day div
    {
        height:50px;
        text-align:right;
        vertical-align:text-top;
    }
</style>
```

I want the center cell of first row is fixed with its content in width, and each cell in second row is 100px in width.

Please let me now if I am doing something wrong or missing something which needs to be added for IE and Chrome

Comment: JSfiddle doesn't even work in my IE.. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want every Day to have a Fixed Width of 100px the whole calendar is supposed to be 700px at all time?

If my assumption is right then change

```
#calHeader,
#calDays
{
    display:table;
    width:700px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the days to always be 100px in width, you have to add:

```
#Calendar
{
     border-collapse:collapse;
     width:700px;
}
```

so the calendar will not stretch when you resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

I think Patrick got it right. I cleaned up the .header.
http://jsfiddle.net/M7Apt/